# Printing file directory into a data structure

Tags: c++

This code is suppose to read and print every single file in the directory, which is does. Now I want to be able to put those files in a data structure. I chose a list and the output cuts off before it gets to the actual file. How can I fix this?

`"C:/Users/deonh/Downloads/intranets/intranet1\\page99.html"` **- What I want** in the list

`C:/Users/deonh/Downloads/intranets/intranet1` **- What I get.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<list>
#include<map>
#include<queue>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
using namespace std;

string path = "C:/Users/deonh/Downloads/intranets/intranet1"; //This gets every single file in the directory

string path5 = "C:/Users/deonh/Downloads/intranets/intranet5";
string path7 = "C:/Users/deonh/Downloads/intranets/intranet7";


int main()
{
    list<string>pages;
    map<string, int> page;


    //Here I am printing the files to make sure the above code works.
    for (const auto& entry : fs::directory_iterator(path)) {

        std::cout << entry.path() << std::endl;
        pages.push_back(path);

    }
    for (list<string> ::iterator it = pages.begin(); it != pages.end(); it++) {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just adding the wrong value to the list

```
pages.push_back(path);
```

should be

```
pages.push_back(entry.path().generic_string());
```

Comment: I tried that originally but I keep running into this error message:     Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) E0304 no instance of overloaded function "std::list<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=std::string, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::string>]" matches the argument list

Comment: Yes, you are right. Edited. The `generic_string()` method produces an `std::string`. There are more string methods that you might want to use.